# Auditing elasticsearch operations

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to find a place in which I can configure/view in my elasticsearch database operation that users perform, like create/delte index.

How can I enable elasticsearch audit for operations like create/delete index?

Answer (score 0):

You should use elasticsearch Cluster log to look for operations like create and deletion of index. If you run Elasticsearch as a service, the default location of the logs varies based on your platform and installation method, for more info check official documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/logging.html).

After locating log files you can use Filebeat to collect log data from your cluster, you can see its recent logs in the Stack Monitoring application. you can use [this tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/configuring-filebeat.html) to set setup Filebeat.